# Inner functions dealing with variables from the scope

Tags: c++, lambda

I have a snippet of code like this:

```
std::list<boost::shared_ptr<Point> > left, right;
// ... fill lists ...

// now, calculate the angle between (right[0], right[1]) and (right[0], left[0])
double alpha = angle(*(right.begin()->get()), *(((++right.begin()))->get()), *(left.begin()->get()) );

std::cout << alpha * 180 / M_PI << std::endl;

if(alpha < 0){
    // do something with the lists, like reversing them. Especially the beginning and end of the lists may change in some way, but "left" and "right" are not reassigned.
}

// calculate the new alpha
alpha = angle(*(right.begin()->get()), *(((++right.begin()))->get()), *(left.begin()->get()) );
```

Apart from the iterator increment magic which may not be too obvoius here without the comments, I'd like to define a function `double alpha()` to reduce the duplication. But because the use of this function is very specific, I'd like to make it a local function. Ideally like that:

```
int a, b;
int sum(){ return a + b; }
a = 5; b = 6;
int s = sum(); // s = 11
a = 3;
s = sum(); // s = 9 now
```

In languages like Python this would be perfectly ok, but how to do this in C++?

EDIT:

This is what I ended up with, special thanks to @wilx and the `-std=c++0x` compiler flag:

```
auto alpha = [&right, &left]() {

    // not 100% correct due to my usage of boost::shared_ptr, but to get the idea

    Point r_first = *(right.begin()); 
    Point l_first = *(left.begin());
    Point r_second = *(++right.begin());

    return angle(r_first, r_second, l_first);
};


if(alpha() < 0) // fix it

double new_alpha = alpha();
```

Comment: C++ have no nested functions. There is an extension in GCC that allows it though, and in the C++11 standard there is [lambda functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Lambda_functions_and_expressions) that might be used instead.

Comment: Is there a reason to use a `list` instead of a `vector`? You wouldn't need the hacky iterator increments if you used a `vector`. Consider also using just a `pair` if the lists always have two elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would suggest using an overload like `angle2(std::list<Point> const &, etc.)`. Two simple arguments is better than what you have now.

With C++11 you could use lambdas that catch their arguments by reference.

If you cannot use C++11 and you do feel adventurous, try Boost.Phoenix (part of Boost.Spirit).

Comment: `auto alpha = [&right, &left]() { return angle(...); }; std::cout << alpha() * 180 / M_PI << std::endl;` -- seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

C++ doesn't support nested functions, but a workaround can be made with function-scoped classes:

```
void scopeFnc()
{
  struct Inner
  {
     static int nestedFnc() { return 5; }
  };

  int a = Inner::nestedFnc();
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean, but `nestedFnc` cannot access variables declared in `scopeFnc`, at least GCC complains about that. But at least this solution helps to reduce the namespace pollution; I can make it using the two lists as arguments.

Comment: @wal-o-mat: fair enough, if you really needed it, you could declare the needed variables inside Inner, but I admit that that wouldn't make your function cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

C++, as far as I know, does not allow this. You can limit the namespace pollution created by appending the static qualifier to the beginning of the function signature for alpha, but you still must define it separately.

This will make the name be used only within that source file. You could also define a macro within the function, being careful to undefine it if you don't want preprocessor weirdness later.

```
int a, b;
#define SUM() (a+b)
int s=sum()
#undef SUM
```